# ASP.NET MVC Sitemap.xml error

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, sitemap, nopcommerce

I have a valid sitemap.xml file. The problem arises when I try to serve this file as a sitemap.xml. I get the following error:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 95: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

When I inspect /sitemap.xml from browser each element tag gets this added to it.

```
<url xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    the rest
</url>
```

Here is how I return the file from the controller:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(@"C:\sitemap.xml");
return Content(xml.DocumentElement.InnerXml, "application/xml");
```

Here is an example of the file I have and trying to return

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset 
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
  <url>
    <loc>LINK</loc>
  </url>
  THE REST OF URLS
</urlset>
```

I have tried switching the "application/xml" to "text/xml" but didn't solve this problem. Am I not using XmlDocument correctly or am I not fully understanding what happens with return Content()?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up fixed this was a simple fix.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(@"C:\sitemap.xml");
return Content(xml.DocumentElement.InnerXml, "application/xml");
```

Changed to

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(@"C:\sitemap.xml");
return Content(xml.DocumentElement.OuterXml, "application/xml");
```

Hope this helps someone later.